# JProperty does not generate double quotes for value

Tags: c#, json, json.net, nancy, double-quotes

I'm trying to create a JSON response that is not based on any class or object.  It is very dynamic in nature.  Hence I've started to use `JObject` from Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.  While it generates the right constructs, it does not encapsulate the value with double quotes.
How can I enforce these double quotes around the values?

Here is a small piece of code I used for testing:

```
var job = new JObject();
job.Add(new JProperty("name", "filip"));
string nm = "Rob";
job.Add(new JProperty("name2", nm));
job.Add(new JProperty("name4", new JValue("Samantha")));
```

Results in:

```
{"name":filip,"name2":Rob,"name4":Samantha}
```

What I would expect:

```
{"name":"filip","name2":"Rob","name4":"Samantha"}
```

Here is a complete example:

```
public class DynJSonService : NancyModule
{
   public DynJSonService()
   {
      Get["/dynjson"] = _ =>
      {
         var job = new JObject();
         job.Add(new JProperty("name", "filip"));
         string nm = "Rob";
         job.Add(new JProperty("name2", nm));
         job.Add(new JProperty("name4", new JValue("Samantha")));
         return job;
      };
   }
}
```

Which results in following response as given through the browser when surfing to the url: `localhost:4439/FilipsApps/dynjson`

```
{"name":filip,"name2":Rob,"name4":Samantha}
```

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this result.  Can you provide a more complete example?

Comment: Hi David, to be complete I have to mention that we are using NancyFx (https://nancyfx.org/) to provide the REST endpoint.  Could the problem be there?

Comment: That depends on what the problem is.  Currently the code shown in the question doesn’t produce the result described in the question.  So it’s not clear what problem you’re observing or where you’re observing it.  Perhaps if you can provide an example which does demonstrate the problem then that would clarify.

Comment: I'll add a complete example.

Comment: What do you mean by "results in" where are you getting that "result" from?

Comment: The result is given through the browser when surfing to the url: http://localhost:4439/FilipsApps/dynjson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nancy uses the [`SimpleJson`](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/Json/SimpleJson.cs) serializer internally by default, which does not know how to handle `JObject` and `JProperty` properly.  If you want to use those, you should configure Nancy to use the Json.Net (a.k.a. Newtonsoft.Json) serializer instead.  There is a [`Nancy.Serialization.JsonNet`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nancy.Serialization.JsonNet/2.0.0-clinteastwood) NuGet package for that.  After you install that package, it should work correctly.  If you need to customize the settings for the Json.Net serializer, there are instructions in the [readme.md](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy.Serialization.JsonNet/blob/master/readme.md) for that package.